# Is kthreadd included in the linux processes?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pid, pstree

I am tasked to implement a simple version of `pstree` (linux command), while I am confused about the content between what `pstree` shows and what I find under `/proc/[pid]` directory.
After I type `pstree`, it shows the root of the whole process tree is `systemd`, just like this:

```
systemd─┬─ECAgent───3*[{ECAgent}]
        ├─EasyMonitor
        ├─ModemManager───2*[{ModemManager}]
        ├─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
```

While after I try to read all `/proc/[pid]/stat` files, I got the following result (do a little formatting):

```
pid  comm       state ppid
1    systemd    S     0
2    kthreadd   S     0
3    rcu_gp     I     2
4    rcu_par_gp I     2
```

It seems that there is another process `kthreadd` that is paralleled with `systemd`. This is different from what shows in `pstree` command.

After reading some manuals and web materials, I know that `pstree` displays all runnnig processes and `kthreadd` is the root thread of all related threads. But I am still confused that `kthreadd` doesn't count as a running process by `pstree` command. So it's like `kthreadd` is not a process even it owns one pid (which is 2)? Should I include `kthreadd` as a running process in my version of `pstree`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is kthreadd process and children and how it is different from init and children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988526/what-is-kthreadd-process-and-children-and-how-it-is-different-from-init-and-chil)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the hint, I've seen that question before posting mine. That question didn't answer about the `pstree` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kthreadd is not a process started by systemd. Kthreadd is a worker thread in kernel address space started by the [kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/init/main.c#L406).

pstree is more to do with the user space processes that shows the parent and child hierarchy.

In my opinion you should not include kthreadd in your implementation.
One of the way to find the kernel threads is /proc/$pid/cmdline is empty for kernel threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, directly responds to my question. So can we say kernel threads are processes, in a broader way? I mean, doesn't `kthreadd` own a PID, which is process id?

Comment: Yes, its a process (more specific to Linux kernel, everything is a task!) with pid 2.

`2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.46 kthreadd`